# How to Display the Folder Structure of sdcard in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, expandablelistview

I create a simple app to display the folder structure of sdcard like I show the screen shot.

[image: Display the Folder Structure of sdcard]

I want to do this type. Which control should I use?

Comment: Should the sections (e.g., 'Animal') be collapsible?

Comment: yes when select folder name Display Sub Directory structure

Answer (score 0):

From the image you posted, i believe the best solution is to use a custom `ListView` with headers, since it seems like that. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is a tutorial for the `ListView`. And [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) is CommonsWare's `CWAC MergeAdapter` to easily add headers in listViews.

Comment: Thanks But it Use for  Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) but i use the Android 2.2. then how to do this?

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh The libraries in my answer are applicable for Android 2.2 also. Even if there is something for new versions of Android, you can always use the compatibility library: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: yes but Device of 2.2 can`t support higher version Api library.so its no solution

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh If you mean the Vogella's tutorial about listViews, it is not only for Android ICS but and for previous versions of Android, and i have used the MergeAdapter in my project that uses the 2.2 Android version and tested it in a 2.2 device and it works.

Comment: you can use the any compatibility library for this?

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh Yes you can use the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for this. However, i do not think you need it to use for what i mention in my answer since they are already supported for Android v2.2.

Answer (score 0):

you might find this helpful: [Getting folder structure from android sdCard device](http://blog.ndroidians.com/sdfolderstructure-getting-folder-structure-from-android-sdcard-device/)